# Redirect to url with commas

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I am trying to write a redirect for urls of this website using flask: http://nachbarschaft.immobilienscout24.de/adressen/bayern,muenchen,haidhausen/dienstleistung/friseur-blatter-hauptverwaltung,66512592.html

The code I use:

```
@app.route('/api/redirect', methods=['GET'])
def redirect_link():
    url = request.values.get('url')
    return redirect(url)
```

The problem is that the target website doesn't decode `%2C` to `,` but to `-` and gives a `404 Not Found`.

Is there any way around this?

Headers with curl:

```
curl -IL http://XXXXXX/api/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnachbarschaft.immobilienscout24.de%2Fadressen%2Fbayern%2Cmuenchen%2Chaidhausen%2Fdienstleistung%2Ffriseur-blatter-hauptverwaltung%2C66512592.html
    HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
    Server: gunicorn/18.0
    Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2013 12:58:26 GMT
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 489
    Location: http://nachbarschaft.immobilienscout24.de/adressen/bayern%2Cmuenchen%2Chaidhausen/dienstleistung/friseur-blatter-hauptverwaltung%2C66512592.html

    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2013 12:58:27 GMT
    Location: /adressen/bayern-muenchen-haidhausen/dienstleistung/friseur-blatter-hauptverwaltung-66512592.html
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-Content-Type-Options: no-sniff
    Cache-Control: max-age=604800, private, must-revalidate
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Set-Cookie: TS8a1db5=ea90e6be799ade80c5c84f3cca057558d12f3da1cca67c5a52a86172; Path=/
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked

    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2013 12:58:27 GMT
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-Content-Type-Options: no-sniff
    Cache-Control: max-age=604800, private, must-revalidate
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Set-Cookie: TS8a1db5=61dcb89e16f8fe72a87d5e1f1faf7b0e82cbf7e476e5a3ff52a86172; Path=/
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: The *first* response in your session appears to be the Flask server; it is redirecting you to the *exact URL* passed in in the `url` parameter; commas and all. The second `301` response appears to be from a **different** server, probably `nachbarshaft.immobilienscout24.de`, and it is redirecting you to a new URL with the dashes. That is **not** Flask's doing.

Comment: Why the target server redirects you is not clear, but it is not a problem that your Flask view is causing. Perhaps that server responds differently based on other browser headers, such as the `Referrer` or the lack of a cookie.

Comment: I agree. But since I don't have access to the other server I was wondering if there is a way to solve this from Flask. In my understanding if the `Location` header was not url encoded it would work.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what you mean here. The server is broken, and when it receives `%2C` instead of `,` in the path it redirects you to a URL with `-` instead.